# Fix for sagging deck rail made of Trek

Tags: deck

Our deck that runs along the lake has a trek railing, top and bottom railings and main posts. We installed vertical black metal balusters. It has been sagging now for awhile. We tried placing blocks underneath but top railings sagged. 
We took down all the railings to repair but not sure what to do. We want to rework what we have to save money. Also, we want to put posts on top of the decking. Is that safe? Just FYI. Our decking runs the length of the water, maybe 50 feet and is about 3’ wide.

Comment: What do you mean by "trek"?  Are you referring to the synthetic/composite wood product known as "Trex"?  That is not wood, is floppy as a noodle, and requires support at much more frequent intervals than wood.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. A picture of this railing would be helpful; if you can't edit the picture into your question, then add the URL and someone will be along to do so.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, it’s not the Trex brand but composite decking of some kind. We took the railings down so it would be difficult to get a complete picture. For clarification, we had put blocks underneath but the top rail is sagging?